# Move comma separated numbers after dot to next line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
0.7,511,300
Lycthythtyjhos
4,465,688
Compusrteterterterve.World
3,827,911
Penthoutrtetet
1.2,148,123
Tripgtrgtrrtg
1,716,682
Dihtyhtyhtyh
01.1,115,456
Nov1995
```

Now I want to select comma separated numbers that **placed after dot** and move them to next line like following:

```
0.
7,511,300
Lycthythtyjhos
4,465,688
Compusrteterterterve.World
3,827,911
Penthoutrtetet
1.
2,148,123
Tripgtrgtrrtg
1,716,682
Dihtyhtyhtyh
01.
1,115,456
Nov1995
```

I tried following regex but not working for me!

```
Find What: (?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)
Replace With: \r\n$&

Find What: ^(?!\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b)[^\d\n]+\K[\d,]+
Replace With: \r\n$&

Find What: ^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$
Replace With: \r\n$&
```

How to fix this problem?
Note that last lines are dates and must keep without any changes.

Comment: If dot is ever found in this one specific place just replace normally one dot `[.]` with dot followed by new line `.\r\n`.

Comment: @Dialecticus no I can't do this because some of files include values like websites domain! and can't do this!

Comment: Maybe just `^\d+\.(?=\d)` and replace with `$0\r\n`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it working! - send as answer that I can accept your answer

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it working but have small problem - it move whole of that line to next line

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, your example text contains only numbers that are pushed on a new line in the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to select comma separated numbers that placed after dot and move
> them to next line like following

```
^\d+\.\K\d+(?:,\d+)+
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits and `.`
- `\K` Forget what is matches so far
- `\d+(?:,\d+)+` Match 1+ digits and repeat 1+ times matching `,` and  1+ digits

To match the whole line and prevent a partial match, add `$` to the end of the regex.

Replace with a newline and the full match:

```
\r\n$0
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MGPfAH/1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these two regex:

```
^\d*\.(?=(\d*(,\d*)*))

^\d+\.(?=(\d+(,\d+)+))
```

- `^\d*\.` matches lines that start with any amount of digits followed by a dot.
- `(?=(\d*(,\d*)*))` matches if the former is followed by a comma-separated number

And replace with this:

```
$0\n
```

Which takes the current match and adds a trailing newline.

Here you can see it in action: https://regex101.com/r/1onYdV/3